# Ubuntu container immediately exits after `docker run ubuntu`

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-10, containers, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am on Windows 10 and I have WSL2 enabled. When I do `docker pull ubuntu` followed by `docker run ubuntu`, a new ubuntu container with a randomly generated name shows up in my dashboard and it starts for half a second, but then immediately stops. If I press the start button the same behaviour is observed. I tried running these commands from Command Prompt, PowerShell, and my downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 distro (which is also my default WSL2 distro) all with the same result.

How do I fix this?

Also, `docker logs <container_name>` doesn't result in anything and double-clicking the container name in the dashboard doesn't show any logs.

Comment: You did not specify a command to run. Put `bash` in the end. Then you also need to add `-it` flag. So `docker run -it ubuntu bash`. At least that.

Comment: In fact, the Ubuntu container runs `bash` by default, but if stdin is closed (no `-i`) it exits immediately. Without `-t` you won't see prompts and many other things won't work. So `docker run -it ubuntu` will get you a bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

A docker container exits when its main process finishes its execution. Now when you check Dockerfile of Ubuntu image you can see the

CMD ["/bin/bash"] which get execute when we start the container.

so if you need to run the container in the background you can do

```
docker run -id --name=myubuntu ubuntu
```

Or you can directly launch the container with an interactive shell using

```
docker run -it --name=myubuntu ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ docker run -d ubuntu bash -c "tail -f /dev/null"
8181cb08da63e8c2b43696155088f1a7da58023d426f11dbc52ec4867a2f5bdf
```

Using a command that hangs (e.g `tail -f /dev/null`) ensures that the container won't close early.

You can then enter the container using

```
$ docker exec -it 8181cb08da63e8c2b43696155088f1a7da58023d426f11dbc52ec4867a2f5bdf /bin/bash
```

To make it easier you could name the container by using the `--name` flag

```
$ docker run -d --name=myubuntu ubuntu bash -c "tail -f /dev/null"
fd534285934a6d62e6955ee330134e342d97a6900f4531f5ee60f729d4c6d43d
```

Then enter the container using

```
$ docker exec -it myubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: by using `/bin/bash` instead of `bash` you will ensure the arrow keys work when scrolling through commands